# How to make links in an iframe relative to the parent URL

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, relative-path

I want relative links inside an `iframe` to be relative to the URL in the address bar, not relative to the `iframe`'s URL. Is this possible?

Modern browser support is all I need.

As an example:
Address bar in browser shows `http://www.example.com/a/b.html`. Inside that webpage is an `iframe` with a `src` of `http://othersite.com/12x982h/index.html`. Within that html, there's a link to `test.html`. When you click on that link, the browser should load a new page at `http://www.example.com/a/test.html`.

***UPDATE***: I don't have control over the `iframe`'s content.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you have control over the iframes content. If my assumptions is correct then that means you can set a "base path" using the [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. All relative URLs will then be "based" on the path you define therein.

Comment: No, I don't have control over the `iframe`'s content.

Comment: I don't think allowing web developers to manipulate link targets inside iframes does much to prevent tricking users. It's still your URL. I could easily pretend I'm the user on my backend and be an intermediate between the real user and the target website, that's even much worse because I'll see the user's passwords.